# Is there an equivalent of std::bind in Dart like there is for C++?

Tags: dart

Suppose I have something like this

```
void funct(int a ,int b)
{
    std::cout << a+b ;//3+2=5
}
```

in C++ we could bind a value to parameter to b so the callback will only have to pass in one parameter. Can we do this in dart ?

```
int main()
{
 auto f = std::bind(&funct,std::placeholders::_1,2); //pass b=2
 f(3);
}
```

Comment: It seems that it is possible. Look for [closure](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#lexical-closures) or [partial application](https://japhr.blogspot.de/2012/01/partial-application-in-dart.html).

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comment below your question, you can accomplish this with a closure:

```
void funct(int a, int b) {
  print(a + b);
}

void main() {
  var f = (b) => funct(2, b);
  f(3);
}
```